# GlassFish 3.1.2 / h:outLabel / How to remove leading line break

Tags: jsf, glassfish, mojarra

I use GlassFish 3.1.2 and figured out, if I use h:outLabel, it generates always a line break.

e.g

```
<h:outputLabel value="" />
```

generates

```
<label>
</label>
```

instead of

```
<label></label>
```

.

And for example

```
<h:outputLabel value="Foo" />/<h:outputLabel value="Bar" />
```

generates

```
<label>
Foo</label>/<label>
Bar</label>
```

which is rendered in my browser as

```
Foo/ Bar
```

but what I wanted, was

```
Foo/Bar
```

.

So I wonder, what is causing this line break, which is rendered as white space?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Are you really using a `<h:outputLabel>` for pure text presentation? You didn't use anywhere its `for` attribute, which indicates that you're actually abusing it for the wrong purpose. To learn what a HTML `<label>` should be used for, read http://www.htmldog.com/reference/htmltags/label/

Comment: @BalusC: No I just simplified the example. So it's more like `<h:outputLabel value="#{msg['myKey']}" />`

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be [a bug](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-1563) in Mojarra 2.0.2. However, as you are using Glassfish 3.1.2 which comes with Mojarra 2.1.16, this should be fixed and I don't really know what the problem is.

You can try to update the Mojarra libs in your Glassfish or you may use `h:outputText` like this:

```
<h:outputText value="Foo" />/<h:outputText value="Bar" />
```

Comment: Thanks! I used 2.1.6 and updated to 2.1.7. The most current version of Mojarra is not compatible with Tomahawk, so I'm not able to update further, until I solved that issue, too.